# Href:tel Breaking

Tags: javascript, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap, google-fusion-tables

I've got a map that's using Fusion Table layers to serve up contact information. I was hoping to add this so the contact information could be dialed from a smartphone.

```
<a href=tel:888-8888>
```

but FT doesn't seem to like that since it keeps throwing back as javascript.void(0) whenever I load it up on my servers.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately we don't currently support tel: in info window links. You might want to add a feature request in our [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables/).